# how to set date and time in single dialog box?

Tags: android, datetimepicker

I am trying to design time date picker in single view but while selecting date,I am able to get system time but while selecting its not displaying selected time this is how I am trying for displaying dialog box but the system tacking by default time not selected time :

```
public class CustomDateTimePicker implements View.OnClickListener {
private DatePicker datePicker;
private TimePicker timePicker;
private ViewSwitcher viewSwitcher;

private final int SET_DATE = 100, SET_TIME = 101, SET = 102, CANCEL = 103;

private Button btn_setDate, btn_setTime, btn_set, btn_cancel;

private Calendar calendar_date = null;

private Activity activity;

private ICustomDateTimeListener iCustomDateTimeListener = null;

private Dialog dialog;

private boolean is24HourView = true, isAutoDismiss = true;

private int selectedHour, selectedMinute;

public CustomDateTimePicker(Activity a,
                            ICustomDateTimeListener customDateTimeListener) {
    activity = a;
    iCustomDateTimeListener = customDateTimeListener;

    dialog = new Dialog(activity);
    dialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
            resetData();
        }
    });

    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    View dialogView = getDateTimePickerLayout();
    dialog.setContentView(dialogView);
}

public View getDateTimePickerLayout() {
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams linear_match_wrap = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams linear_wrap_wrap = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams frame_match_wrap = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams button_params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f);

    LinearLayout linear_main = new LinearLayout(activity);
    linear_main.setLayoutParams(linear_match_wrap);
    linear_main.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    linear_main.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    LinearLayout linear_child = new LinearLayout(activity);
    linear_child.setLayoutParams(linear_wrap_wrap);
    linear_child.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    LinearLayout linear_top = new LinearLayout(activity);
    linear_top.setLayoutParams(linear_match_wrap);
    btn_setDate = new Button(activity);
    btn_setDate.setLayoutParams(button_params);
    btn_setDate.setText("Set Date");
    btn_setDate.setId(SET_DATE);
    btn_setDate.setOnClickListener(this);

    btn_setTime = new Button(activity);
    btn_setTime.setLayoutParams(button_params);
    btn_setTime.setText("Set Time");
    btn_setTime.setId(SET_TIME);
    btn_setTime.setOnClickListener(this);

    linear_top.addView(btn_setDate);
    linear_top.addView(btn_setTime);

    viewSwitcher = new ViewSwitcher(activity);
    viewSwitcher.setLayoutParams(frame_match_wrap);

    datePicker = new DatePicker(activity);
    timePicker = new TimePicker(activity);
    timePicker.setOnTimeChangedListener(new TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            selectedHour = hourOfDay;
            selectedMinute = minute;
        }
    });

    viewSwitcher.addView(timePicker);
    viewSwitcher.addView(datePicker);

    LinearLayout linear_bottom = new LinearLayout(activity);
    linear_match_wrap.topMargin = 8;
    linear_bottom.setLayoutParams(linear_match_wrap);

    btn_set = new Button(activity);
    btn_set.setLayoutParams(button_params);
    btn_set.setText("Set");
    btn_set.setId(SET);
    btn_set.setOnClickListener(this);

    btn_cancel = new Button(activity);
    btn_cancel.setLayoutParams(button_params);
    btn_cancel.setText("Cancel");
    btn_cancel.setId(CANCEL);
    btn_cancel.setOnClickListener(this);

    linear_bottom.addView(btn_set);
    linear_bottom.addView(btn_cancel);

    linear_child.addView(linear_top);
    linear_child.addView(viewSwitcher);
    linear_child.addView(linear_bottom);

    linear_main.addView(linear_child);

    return linear_main;
}

public void showDialog() {
    if (!dialog.isShowing()) {
        if (calendar_date == null)
            calendar_date = Calendar.getInstance();

        selectedHour = calendar_date.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        selectedMinute = calendar_date.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        datePicker.setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
        timePicker.setIs24HourView(is24HourView);
        timePicker.setCurrentHour(selectedHour);
        timePicker.setCurrentMinute(selectedMinute);

        datePicker.updateDate(calendar_date.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                calendar_date.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                calendar_date.get(Calendar.DATE));

        dialog.show();

        btn_setDate.performClick();
    }
}

public void setAutoDismiss(boolean isAutoDismiss) {
    this.isAutoDismiss = isAutoDismiss;
}

public void dismissDialog() {
    if (!dialog.isShowing())
        dialog.dismiss();
}

public void setDate(Calendar calendar) {
    if (calendar != null)
        calendar_date = calendar;
}

public void setDate(Date date) {
    if (date != null) {
        calendar_date = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar_date.setTime(date);
    }
}

public void setDate(int year, int month, int day) {
    if (month < 12 && month >= 0 && day < 32 && day >= 0 && year > 100
            && year < 3000) {
        calendar_date = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar_date.set(year, month, day);
    }

}

public void setTimeIn24HourFormat(int hourIn24Format, int minute) {
    if (hourIn24Format < 24 && hourIn24Format >= 0 && minute >= 0
            && minute < 60) {
        if (calendar_date == null)
            calendar_date = Calendar.getInstance();

        calendar_date.set(calendar_date.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                calendar_date.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                calendar_date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), hourIn24Format,
                minute);

        is24HourView = true;
    }
}

public void setTimeIn12HourFormat(int hourIn12Format, int minute,
                                  boolean isAM) {
    if (hourIn12Format < 13 && hourIn12Format > 0 && minute >= 0
            && minute < 60) {
        if (hourIn12Format == 12)
            hourIn12Format = 0;

        int hourIn24Format = hourIn12Format;

        if (!isAM)
            hourIn24Format += 12;

        if (calendar_date == null)
            calendar_date = Calendar.getInstance();

        calendar_date.set(calendar_date.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                calendar_date.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                calendar_date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), hourIn24Format,
                minute);

        is24HourView = false;
    }
}

public void set24HourFormat(boolean is24HourFormat) {
    is24HourView = is24HourFormat;
}

public interface ICustomDateTimeListener {
    public void onSet(Dialog dialog, Calendar calendarSelected,
                      Date dateSelected, int year, String monthFullName,
                      String monthShortName, int monthNumber, int date,
                      String weekDayFullName, String weekDayShortName, int hour24,
                      int hour12, int min, int sec, String AM_PM);

    public void onCancel();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case SET_DATE:
            btn_setTime.setEnabled(true);
            btn_setDate.setEnabled(false);
            viewSwitcher.showNext();
            break;

        case SET_TIME:
            btn_setTime.setEnabled(false);
            btn_setDate.setEnabled(true);
            viewSwitcher.showPrevious();
            break;

        case SET:
            if (iCustomDateTimeListener != null) {
                int month = datePicker.getMonth();
                int year = datePicker.getYear();
                int day = datePicker.getDayOfMonth();


                calendar_date.set(year, month, day, selectedHour,
                        selectedMinute);

                iCustomDateTimeListener.onSet(dialog, calendar_date,
                        calendar_date.getTime(), calendar_date
                                .get(Calendar.YEAR),
                        getMonthFullName(calendar_date.get(Calendar.MONTH)),
                        getMonthShortName(calendar_date.get(Calendar.MONTH)),
                        calendar_date.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar_date
                                .get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
                        getWeekDayFullName(calendar_date
                                .get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)),
                        getWeekDayShortName(calendar_date
                                .get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)), calendar_date
                                .get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
                        getHourIn12Format(calendar_date
                                .get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)), calendar_date
                                .get(Calendar.MINUTE), calendar_date
                                .get(Calendar.SECOND), getAMPM(calendar_date));

            }
            if (dialog.isShowing() && isAutoDismiss)
                dialog.dismiss();
            break;

        case CANCEL:
            if (iCustomDateTimeListener != null)
                iCustomDateTimeListener.onCancel();
            if (dialog.isShowing())
                dialog.dismiss();
            break;
    }
}

/**
 * @param date
 *            date in String
 * @param fromFormat
 *            format of your <b>date</b> eg: if your date is 2011-07-07
 *            09:09:09 then your format will be <b>yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss</b>
 * @param toFormat
 *            format to which you want to convert your <b>date</b> eg: if
 *            required format is 31 July 2011 then the toFormat should be
 *            <b>d MMMM yyyy</b>
 * @return formatted date
 */
public static String convertDate(String date, String fromFormat,
                                 String toFormat) {
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(fromFormat);
        Date d = simpleDateFormat.parse(date);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(d);

        simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(toFormat);
        simpleDateFormat.setCalendar(calendar);
        date = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return date;
}

private String getMonthFullName(int monthNumber) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthNumber);

    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM");
    simpleDateFormat.setCalendar(calendar);
    String monthName = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());

    return monthName;
}

private String getMonthShortName(int monthNumber) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthNumber);

    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM");
    simpleDateFormat.setCalendar(calendar);
    String monthName = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());

    return monthName;
}

private String getWeekDayFullName(int weekDayNumber) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, weekDayNumber);

    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
    simpleDateFormat.setCalendar(calendar);
    String weekName = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());

    return weekName;
}

private String getWeekDayShortName(int weekDayNumber) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, weekDayNumber);

    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EE");
    simpleDateFormat.setCalendar(calendar);
    String weekName = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());

    return weekName;
}

private int getHourIn12Format(int hour24) {
    int hourIn12Format = 0;

    if (hour24 == 0)
        hourIn12Format = 12;
    else if (hour24 <= 12)
        hourIn12Format = hour24;
    else
        hourIn12Format = hour24 - 12;

    return hourIn12Format;
}

private String getAMPM(Calendar calendar) {
    String ampm = (calendar.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == (Calendar.AM)) ? "AM"
            : "PM";
    return ampm;
}

private void resetData() {
    calendar_date = null;
    is24HourView = true;
}

public static String pad(int integerToPad) {
    if (integerToPad >= 10 || integerToPad < 0)
        return String.valueOf(integerToPad);
    else
        return "0" + String.valueOf(integerToPad);
}}
```

**And this is My MainActivity for calling DateTime picker dialog**

```
custom = new CustomDateTimePicker(this,
            new CustomDateTimePicker.ICustomDateTimeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onSet(Dialog dialog, Calendar calendarSelected,
                                  Date dateSelected, int year, String monthFullName,
                                  String monthShortName, int monthNumber, int date,
                                  String weekDayFullName, String weekDayShortName,
                                  int hour24, int hour12, int min, int sec,
                                  String AM_PM)
                {


                    sheduleDate.setText(year
                            + "-" + (monthNumber + 1) + "-" + calendarSelected.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
                            + " " + hour12 + ":" + min
                            + ":" + sec);
                    sheduleDate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    setShedule =sheduleDate.getText().toString();
                    sheduleDate.setText("");

                }
```

Comment: this thing happen in lollipop only

Comment: try this https://github.com/jjobes/SlideDateTimePicker

Comment: @Munir thanks for that but its not working property its giving error am alrady try out this ectuly i need to datetime picker with single view hide back date and time also but its not working for lolipop

Comment: can any one help me on this why the time is not get selected on API 21